# shift click on svg element loaded with <object> does not work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg

I do not seem to be able to detect a shift click on an svg element in Chrome (52.0.2743.116) with the following code.  The code works fine in both IE and Firefox.  Chrome detects regular mouse clicks, but not when the shift key is depressed.  Chrome does detect double shift clicks. I've also found that Chrome will detect shift clicks if the svg is loaded inline.  The problem only appears when an external svg is loaded with an object tag.  Is this a Chrome bug, or am I doing something foolish?  Are there any workarounds that will work on all browsers?

The html and javascript:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <object data="junk.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
    <script>
       function selectElement(event) {
            console.log("Mouse click detected");
            if (event.shiftKey) {
                console.log("Shift key is depressed!");
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

junk.svg:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">

    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="120.5px" height="97px" viewBox="0 0 120.5 97" style="enable- background:new 0 0 120.5 97;" xml:space="preserve">

    <rect x="31.5" y="28" onclick="parent.selectElement(evt)" style="stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;" width="62" height="43"/>

    </svg>
```

Comment: If you've found a Chrome bug, report it to [Chrome's bugtracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/entry).

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Will do!